# Image not being responsive. I have tried both adding img-responsive class and setting height to auto in css

Tags: html, css

This is my html code.

```
  <div class="column">
        <div class="slider" id="main-slider">
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <img src="images/11.jpg" class="slide img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the css part.

```
img{
    border-color: white; border-radius: 8px;border: 1px solid #ddd;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 5% 80px 0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

The image not being responsive. I have tried both adding img-responsive class and setting height to auto in css. It does not shrink when I reduce the browser size.

Comment: You should include rest of your  CSS code too.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap  4 use `img-fluid`  instead of `img-responsive`. Read its documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/)

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v3.3.5

Comment: So why do you tag `Bootstrap-4`?

Answer (score 0):

I have put your code into JSFiddle with an image without the img-responsive class and everything seems to be working fine?

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="slider" id="main-slider">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <img src="https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zhg95pa8/

Delete the class and see if that works any better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code

```
img {
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 5% 80px 0;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width="100%"` to `<img>` tag and remove width from img css part. That's it :)

```css
img{
    border-color: white; border-radius: 8px;border: 1px solid #ddd;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 5% 80px 0;
    /*width:100%;*/
    /*height:auto;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
        <div class="slider" id="main-slider">
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
                <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/1928643/screenshots/4451111/shot3.jpg" class="slide img-responsive" width="100%">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```